# How to make Snipping Tool in Windows 10 start taking a screenshot by clicking its icon in taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, gui, screenshot, simplification

I simply want to make it start taking a screenshot right after clicking its icon in the Taskbar. Unfortunatelly, now the situation is different. This how it works now:

### BAD VARIANT

1. click the icon in the Taskbar.
2. **Click New.** - *I want to remove this step.*
3. Select the area.
4. Save.

---

BUT, Here is ***what I want:***

### GOOD VARIANT

1. click the icon in Taskbar.
2. Select the area.
3. Save.

---

___In other words, I want to remove one step - clicking New which is step 2 in the Bad Variant.
***I want to start taking a screenshot right after clicking the icon in the Taskbar.***

Please, help me with the GOOD VARIANT.

- P.S. Some years ago I found the solution for my older version of Windows (that was either Windows 7 or XP; I don't remember), but I cannot find it now.
- P.S.S. Let me explain my scenario again: 1) click ICON 2) start choosing the area 3) The resulting snip gets opened in the same Snipping Tool (or similar soft, OK, I am tired of waiting for Microsoft's mercy).  ALL IN ONE APP. I really don't want to press any buttons on keyboards, or make any other movent with my finger. I am not being arrogant; I just need to be fast at work.

[image]

Comment: The snippet tool doesn't have this functionality.  Windows XP didn't have a built-in snippet tool.  Windows 8+ come with a different version then what came with Windows 7, functionality has changed, find another tool

Comment: I remember that I used Snipping Tool right away, without clciking New. That was either XP or Windows 7; I do not remember. Anyway, I am sure there can be some solution to my question, and without installing any other soft.

Comment: Windows XP did not come with a snipping tool, and Windows 8+ snipping tool doesn't have this feature.  You can't make Software do something it wasn't written to do

Comment: It was definitely not Windows 8. I preferred to skip that version because of the rumours that it broke SSDs).

Comment: If you want quick process, press Win+Print Screen and edit the image in paint.

Comment: Starting with Win8, you have to click on "new", for Windows 7, the selection was started automatically. MS changed it since Win8

Comment: @SergeyLarin I know what version of Windows the snipping tool changed...

Comment: Install Greenshot.

Comment: @Alan B
So, does it work like Snipping Tool used to? 
I need to:
1) click the icon to start the program. 2) NO New image, just ready to take a screenshot. 3) after choosing the area I can draw in the image. AND WITHOUT ANY ADDITIONAL STEPS!

Comment: So, like, in the old Snipping Tool, which had the same functionality.

Comment: @Sergey, install it, it liads with Windows. Hit one of the configurable hotkeys to capture screen, window or draggable region. Then a menu pops up and ypu can directly save, open in its own editor, open in Paint or any other installed editor, email, send to Instagram etc

Comment: @Alan B and the other speakers here. Let me explain my scenario again:
1) click ICON 2) start choosing the area 3) It is opened in the same Snipping tool app. 
ALL IN ONE APP. 
I really don't want to press any buttons on keyboards, or make any other movent with my finger. I am not being arrogant; I just need to be fast at work.

Comment: In Windows 11 there's an option to do this directly. Go to Settings -> Accessibility -> Turn on Use the Print Screen button to open screen snipping

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is old but I just got it working.

1. Click Start and type Snipping Tool.
2. Right click the "Snipping Tool" icon and click "Open file location".
   Note: This will open the shortcut under `"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories"`.
3. Right click the "Snipping Tool" icon and click on Properties.
4. Under Target, enter this: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\SnippingTool.exe /clip`
5. Click Apply. You will need admin permissions to do this.
6. Click continue, now drag and drop the Snipping Tool icon from `"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories"` into your taskbar.

Comment: Is there a way to keep snipping tool open after taking the clip?

Comment: Tiago Caldeira, thank you. Now the Snipping Tool opens just like I need. However, there is one critical problem now. After the take the screenshot, where are the screenshots? I cannot find them anywhere. Do they get saved in some special folder? It simply seems to me the screenshots do not get saved anywhere. After I take the screenshot there is no dialogue on where to save the image.

Comment: The pic gets copied in clipboard. You can paste it on documents you are working on.

Comment: My case is different. I do not need to save them. I just need to:
 1) click the icon,
2) take screenshot, 
3) see it instantly, and be able to draw in it.

Comment: In other words - I would like to use just my mouse, and make as little clicks as possible. I want to click the icon, and right after clciking start choosing the area. You see, now things work in another way - you have to click the icon, and CLICK NEW, and only after this you can choose the area. 
I want to remove the 'New' step.

Comment: Also looking for a way to replicate what the OP wanted. Click the New button and have all other behaviour the same. This simply copies to clipboard rather than open the snip to then edit/save/whatever... Automatic naming and saving would also be a good alternative.

Comment: In Windows 11 there's an option to do this directly. Go to Settings -> Accessibility -> Turn on Use the Print Screen button to open screen snipping

Comment: so, instead of using a mouse you proposed me to use a keyboard, but the question is about a mouse, sorry. If you are Ok with blindtyping, then I understand your choice. Also, my machine does not support Windows 11 even though the specs are good.

Answer (score 1):

If Windows 8+ don't have this functionality, one bodge solution you could use is to create a non-Windows app that will open Snipping Tool and then immediately send the Alt-N command to the Snipping Tool. Something like AutoHotKey should be able to do that.

Comment: I am fed up with AutoKey, because it has some bugs which make my computer games function in a wrong way. And yes, I tried exceptions and all.